# How does systemd units or services Stdout and Stderr are read by the journald service

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

How reading of streams (More specifically piping of `Stdout`, `Stderr`, `Stdin` streams) done for Systemd services in `journald`? Can I redirect the Stream of one service to another service ? How do I configure `Systemd` Unit to pipe `Stdout` of one service as `Stdin` of another?

Comment: Usage of `StandardInput=` is explained [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html). It seems like you can define a FIFO or a service in a `.socket` to get your `std` forwarded.

Comment: socket will restarts every time client connects to socket, i want to keep on pumping the messages to stream, while other service reads it.